# How would old software using the SIGPIPE signal really work if it were to manage _many_ pipes?

Tags: unix, c

I'm wondering what was the thinking behind having a `SIGPIPE` signal.

From my own experience, the first thing I do is turn off that signal (`SIGIGN`) and use the return value of the calls to make sure it isn't now closed (i.e. `errno == EPIPE`).

The only one thing I could come up with is: programmers at the time wanted to pipe between processes in a shell so they would do work until the first `SIGPIPE` and just exit. However, even that, if you pipe-in and pipe-out, then you'd need to know whether the `SIGPIPE` was for the input and if so continue the work until your data was all processed... I guess you can first assume that the `SIGPIPE` was from the input and not fail. If you receive `SIGPIPE` again, just fail.

So even early on, the signal would be difficult to work with, wouldn't it?

P.S. I'm not interested about sockets that came later.

Comment: You don't "need to know whether the SIGPIPE was for the input" because it was only generated when *writing* to a broken pipe. It was a nice simple way to write a filter without doing *any* error checking. If for any reason the filter can't write to a pipe, SIGPIPE kills it. That's better than the filter eating up resources processing more input when there is nowhere for the output to go.

Comment: @alephzero mind to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You get `SIGPIPE` only if you try to *write* to a pipe that has no readers anymore. The idea is that typical unix processes run to produce output. If the output is going to a pipe, but no one is reading from a pipe, the process got useless and may be killed.

You never get `SIGPIPE` reading from an input pipe. If you read from an input pipe that has no writers anymore, you just get EOF. The usual behaviour of a process that reads EOF is finishing input processing. So you get the behaviour you suggest for nice filters "for free" without adding extra logic like counting `SIGPIPE`s.

The idea of the default behaviour is meant to make the standard UNIX idiom of reading standard input, transforming it in some way, and writing the result to standard output work by default. If your process writes to files in a more complex patterns, it often is a good idea to change the default "process is killed by SIGPIPE" behaviour. But in this case your process is already complex enough that the extra complexity of changing `SIGPIPE` handling doesn't significantly affect binary size or runtime.

Comment: Unix programs frequently don't check for successful writes to stdout.  How many programs worry about the return value from *printf*?

Comment: @another-dave Indeed. And thus it seems like it would have made sense to have every output write error kill the process. Writing to a dead pipe makes just as little sense as writing to a full disk. Yet there is no SIGSPC that you receive by default instead of an -ENOSPC return value.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Not really. If my text editor can't save my file, I don't want it to throw away the only extant copy.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 A text editor is part of the "very complex software" which will catch the _SIGSPC_...

Comment: @AlexisWilke Imagine it's buggy, or the programmer forgot. “Claims to have saved the file but didn't” is much better than [“pressing save is a risky action”](http://holyjoe.org/poetry/anonF.htm) as a default behaviour.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I'm not sure it *is* that much better - if the editor says it's saved, I'll very likely exit and go on and do something else, in which case (a) I've still lost my edits, and (b) I have been given no indication that there is even a problem :-/

Comment: @psmears The kind of "text editor" that doesn't check whether the file is saved is the kind that doesn't show a "saved" message, and I'm always wary of those. But even if not – consider the situation after you know there's a problem with the software.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: *Any* text editor that has "doesn't handle saving very well" as a bug is to be avoided... that is true regardless of any advantages or otherwise of a (hypothetical) SIGNOSPC signal :)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Much of the design of C and Unix libraries assumes expert programmers. Of course, the truth is the reason why buffer overflows have been a long-standing problem....